# Local Dev Server for AWS Lambdas

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a dev server that runs AWS Lambdas locally? My requirements would be

- `nodejs` server, no `ruby` or `go` or anything need to install other than `node` and `npm` packages
- Creates a server that I can query via `wget` / `curl` or an API testing tool to send various events to
- I should be able to specify a `js` file that the server uses as lambda and the server should restart / update when I change that file

Comment: Have you tried serverless framework with serverless offline plugin for AWS API Gateway and Lambda simulation locally?

Comment: Maybe the [Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) IDE could work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not require `serverless` or `claudiajs`.

I usually just write my own little `express` script for this purpose. I always just use Lambda Proxy integration so it's simpler.

Something like this...

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')

// Two different Lambda handlers
const { api } = require('../src/api')
const { login } = ('../src/login')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

// route and their handlers
app.post('/login', lambdaProxyWrapper(login))
app.all('/*', lambdaProxyWrapper(api))


app.listen(8200, () => console.info('Server running on port 8200...'))


function lambdaProxyWrapper(handler) {
  return (req, res) => {
    // Here we convert the request into a Lambda event
    const event = {
      httpMethod: req.method,
      queryStringParameters: req.query,
      pathParameters: {
        proxy: req.params[0],
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    }

    return handler(event, null, (err, response) => {
      res.status(response.statusCode)
      res.set(response.headers)

      return res.json(JSON.parse(response.body))
    })
  }
}
```

Then, run it with `nodemon` so it watches the files and reloads as necessary.

```
nodemon --watch '{src,scripts}/**/*.js' scripts/server.js
```

Comment: Seems legit and since the other answers and comments have a huge overhand or are not JS I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out SAM Local? https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local

Comment: Sorry, SAM Local is written in GO and made for SAM, I don't want to install GO stuff nor SAM (which SAM Local uses). Thanks though.

Comment: Not quite a server, but JS at least and it runs locally from the command line: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local