# How to reuse AWS lambdas into express server / or best practice for local development

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I am having a serverless APP that is AWS lambda base and I am also having express for the local development.
I found it quite useless to maintain the code in two places and start thinking about some solution to reuse the lambda.ts file (if it is even possible not sure).
The only idea that came into my head was, somehow parse the file (lambda.ts file) -> extract code -> generate the source code automatically.

Would be super nice to get some advice and opinion as I cant find anything similar in the internet.
[sample structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHT18.png)

P.S
I also like to add a test cover to the existing ci-cd pipeline (gitHub) but as it going to test the express-server file it makes the test itself absolutely not logical, as the code at lambda can have a typo, mistakes,varois error which was missed during the code copy-pasting (e.g lambda has -> APIGatewayProxyEvent | express ->  Request)

Comment: seems similar question but the suggestions is not exactly what I am looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660868/local-dev-server-for-aws-lambdas?rq=1

Comment: Can't help much with Express, but as a tip for local development, use the Serverless framework. It has the invoke-local functionality that'll run your lambda locally.

Comment: @almarc thank you for the advice - will have a look into it, seems only one real solution!